# is it possible to concatenate a value of a variable into the ACCEPT prompt text?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to add a value of a variable into the accept prompt box in oracle developer

```
ACCEPT  confirm  char  PROMPT 'Are you sure you want to delete org_name ?  ' ||org_name ;
```

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SET VERIFY OFF
VARIABLE org_name VARCHAR2(100);
VARIABLE STATUS VARCHAR2(100);
```

```
ACCEPT p_orgid CHAR PROMPT 'Enter organization ID: ';
```

This is my Code:

```
    DECLARE
        orgname     VARCHAR(200);  
    BEGIN
        SELECT
            name
        INTO
            :org_name
        FROM
            table
        WHERE
            o_id = '&p_orgid';
        IF
            SQL%found
        THEN
            dbms_output.put_line('Are you sure you want to delete ( '
            || :org_name
            || ' ) ? ');
            :STATUS :=  :org_name || ' has been deleted';  
        END IF;   
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN no_data_found THEN
            dbms_output.put_line('No Data Found ');     
    END;
    /


ACCEPT  confirm  char  PROMPT 'Are you sure you want to delete org_name ?  ' ||org_name ;
```

The returned org_name should be displayed in prompt box , Accept prompt does not seem to accept variable values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use NEW_VALUE to translate `:org_name` (bind variable) to `&nv` (substitution variable) as shown below.  Substitution variables are recognized inside ACCEPT strings.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36076201/11611377)

```
.
.
EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('No Data Found ');     
END;
/

COLUMN mybvcol NEW_VALUE nv NOPRINT
SELECT :org_name mybvcol FROM dual;

ACCEPT confirm  char  PROMPT 'Are you sure you want to delete org_name "&nv"?';
```

Answer (score 0):

I can show you how to do that in SQL*Plus. See if you can make it work in SQL Developer.

For testing purposes, I've created a test table in Scott's schema as

```
SQL> create table test as select * from dept;

Table created.
```

The script looks like this (I named it "cont" as *continue script execution if ...*):

```
select * from test;

prompt Which deptno do you want to delete?
accept p_deptno prompt 'Deptno : ';

set verify off;
set heading off;

select 'Are you sure you want to delete ' || d.dname || '? '
from test d
where d.deptno = &p_deptno;

accept odg prompt 'Y / N : ' ;

set termout off;
set pause off;
set echo off;
column a newline;
spool c:\temp\odg.sql

select decode(upper('&odg'), 'Y', 'prompt Executing ...',
                                  'prompt Stopped'
              ),
       decode(upper('&odg'), 'Y', '', 'accept return_key prompt ''Press <Return>''') a,
       decode(upper('&odg'), 'Y', '', 'exit') a
from dual;

spool off;
set termout on;

@c:\temp\odg       

delete from test where deptno = &p_deptno;

select * from test;

accept return_key prompt 'Press <Return>'
exit;
```

Let's see how it works:

```
SQL> @cont

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

Which deptno do you want to delete?
Deptno : 20

Are you sure you want to delete RESEARCH?

Y / N : y
Executing ...

1 row deleted.


        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

Press <Return>
Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

c:\Temp>
```

---

In SQL Developer, you'd run it as

```
c:\temp\cont.sql
```

(you'd write that into the Worksheet) and execute it as a script. SQL Developer will prompt you for parameters; watch the execution in Script output window.